# Como injetar uma variável em uma página que foi requerida por uma função

Tags: php, mvc

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou utilizando um modelo MVC para um CMS em PHP de estudo, porém eu gostaria que fosse possível utilizar temas, para isso criei uma variável de configuração que armazena o nome do tema para **testar**, e quando utilizo meu *controller* para chamar minha *view*, fica da seguinte forma:

```
$this->render('view_posts', $parametros);
```

Nessa função eu passo a *view* que vou utilizar e vetor `$parametros`, que contém título da página, descrição, conteúdo, etc. Minha função render() está assim:

```
private function render($view, $parametros)
{
  require_once(_APP_ROOT . '/view/' . $view.'.php');
}
```

Se eu tentar pegar o vetor `$parametros` na `view_posts.php` funciona sem problemas, porém como eu disse eu queria que suportasse temas, então na `view_posts.php` eu tenho um `require_once` com o nome do tema e a página correspondente.

```
require_once(_APP_ROOT . '/tema/' . _TESTE_TEMA . 'index_view.php');
```

E na `index_view.php` do meu tema ele não reconhece o vetor `$parametros`.

Como posso resolver este problema? Acredito que seja um problema fácil de resolver porém já estou um pouco cego nesse projeto e não consigo encontrar uma solução.

Um detalhe que gostaria de citar é que **não estou utilizando nenhum *framework*, e também não gostaria de utilizar** por se tratar de um CMS de estudo.

Comment: é exibido o erro "Notice: Undefined variable: parametros" ou algum outro?

Comment: Exatamente, como se eu nunca tivesse definido.

Comment: nenhum ideia de possível causa, mas usar a função `get_defined_vars()` num *debug* pode te auxiliar

Comment: Eu encontrei isso "When you included the template file, you did the operation WITHIN the header function, thus making all $page variable in the template file referring to the local $page variable in the header function, which apparently is not declared/defined." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962321/undefined-variable-after-using-require-once - Porém ainda não sei como vou aplicar ao meu caso, pois se tratando de MVC, minhas views são "burras", não sei como iria passar isso pro meu tema.

Comment: Vou te dar uma dica que pode ser útil para o seu propósito: Experimente essa biblioteca (não é framework, é só um plugin) -> http://platesphp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma, e passar os parâmetros:

```
   class View
    {
        function render($file, $variables = [])
        {
            extract($variables);

            ob_start();
            include_once _APP_ROOT .
                         DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
                         'tema' . 
                         DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
                         func_get_args(0) . '.php';
            $renderedView = ob_get_clean();
            return $renderedView;
        }
    }

    $view = new View();
    echo $view->render('view_posts', ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Comment: Ivan, uma dica, ao invés, de `include $file`, use `include func_get_arg(0)`. Pois o extract pode fazer com que a variável `$file` seja sobrescrita.

Comment: é verdade. Agora ele pegará sempre o primeiro argumento passado, independente do segundo parâmetro a ser um `['file'=>'valor']` ...

Comment: poderia passar no `extract(func_get_args(1));` e no método, tirar os parâmetros `function render(){...}`. Um passo para a programação funcional...

Comment: Ivan, sua dica me ajudou muito mesmo! Eu achava que por causa de ser uma view, ela não poderia ser uma classe, mas eu estava enganado, e funcionou corretamente. Vou marcar sua resposta como melhor resposta,mas também irei postar a minha solução, pois pode ajudar alguém.

Comment: Que bom! Fico feliz que tenha contribuído para o seu projeto, boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Ivan Ferrer ajudou muito, porém aqui está a minha solução para caso sirva para mais alguém.

No meu controller minha função render() ficou assim:

```
public function render()
    {   
        $template = new template(__DIR_MEU_template, __SITE_WWW);
        $view = new view($template);
        $view->render('index_view', ['output' => 'má oeeee' ]);
    }
```

E minha classe view

```
class view
{
    private $template;

    public function __construct($template)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    public function render($view, $vars = [])
    {
        require_once($this->template->get_diretorio() . $view . '.php');
    }
}
```

Ainda está extremamente simples e estou usando constantes para testar, mas essa é a lógica,assim posso chamar qualquer variável que for passada para a classe view em meu tema.

Obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: Só uma dica simples, o método da classe `$template` foi injetado dentro dessa classe, para ficar mais claro e reforçar a injeção de dependência, coloque o tipo dela: `public function __construct(Template $template)`. Fica mais compreensível para quem for mexer futuramente no seu código.